# Search the VBA source code with RegEx

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I need to find all the occurrences of a particular RegEx in my source code (i.e. `col*r` ). I realized you can programmatically search through your code for patterns (RegEx) if you use the `VBComponents.CodeModule.Find()` method as it's explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118061/how-to-search-through-vba-code-files) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443952%28v=vs.60%29.aspx). But that does not meet my needs as it only tells you whether such expression is found or not. I need the actual expression found in the module as well (e.g. `colour` and `color`).

Is there any way to achieve this programmatically within VBA?

Comment: Instead of using the `Find()` method you could use a vbscript regexp to do the search: this has an `Execute` method which returns one or more `Match` objects, from which you can get the matched text.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx

Comment: Have a look at the second version here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612675/find-function-in-form-code-module/9616438#9616438

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim re, match
Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
re.Pattern = "your regex"
re.Global = True

For Each match In re.Execute("you input")
    MsgBox match.Value
Next
```

for more information check this link:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx